# AJAX: Disabling submit button until username field is filled with email

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My login page have three things:

1. Field for the username
2. Field for the password
3. Submit button

This code will disable the submit button if the username field is not empty.

I want to disable the submit button until the username field is filled with a email.

Additionally, After wrote something in the username field and clear it, the submit button does not disable itself. I want the submit button to disable itself after clearing the username field.

```
$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
 $('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '<!-- not sure what to put here -->') {
       $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RegEx to validate email. You have to disable the button if the condition is `false` like the following way:

```js
let button = $(':input[type="submit"]');
button.prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
  if(validateEmail($(this).val())) {
     button.prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
    button.prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
 
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!!
I got another question, what does 
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
mean ?
and how did you come up with it?

Comment: @DanCode, that is a pattern which test the input value for valid email pattern. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

A pure js solution for this would be:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=email]").onkeyup = function(){
let reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
(this.value.length==0 || reg.test(this.value)==false)?document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").setAttribute("disabled","disabled"):document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").removeAttribute("disabled")
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="email">
<input type="password">
<input type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

This checks the length of the input value or the input pattern whenever a key is released. If the length is zero or the pattern does not match, then it sets the disabled attribute to disabled. If not, it removes the attribute disabled altogether.